# Problems displaying a transposed method?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, transpose

I'm trying to write a program that prints a randomly generated matrix and a transposed matrix, but I can't quite figure it out.
When I attempt to compile I get the error on line 41 "error: cannot find symbol printMatrix(transposedMatrix);
            ^
I've worked on this for a few hours now and can't figure it out, thanks in advance for the help.

I apologize if the formatting for this code is a little off, it looks fine in Sublime and I'm not not used to this site.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int rows = 0;
int cols = 0;

while (rows < 1 || rows > 10) {
System.out.print("Enter the number of rows (1-10): ");
int userRows = input.nextInt();

if (userRows < 1 || userRows > 10) {
  System.out.println("ERROR! The number of rows cannot be outside the specified range of 1-10!");
}
else userRows += rows;
}

while (cols < 1 || cols > 10) {
System.out.print("Enter the number of columns (1-10): ");
int userCols = input.nextInt();

if (userCols < 1 || userCols > 10) {
  System.out.println("ERROR! The number of columns cannot be outside the speified range of 1-10!");
}
else userCols += cols;
}

int[][] originalMatrix = new int[rows][cols];

for (int row = 0; row < originalMatrix.length; row++)
  for (int col = 0; col < originalMatrix[row].length; col++) {
    originalMatrix[row][col] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
  }

System.out.println("\nOriginal matrix:");
printMatrix(originalMatrix);

System.out.println("\nTransposed matrix:");
printMatrix(transposedMatrix);
}

public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
    System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + "  ");
  }
  System.out.println();
} 
} 

public static int[][] transposedMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
int m = matrix.length;
int n = matrix[0].length;
int[][] transposedMatrix = new int[n][m];
for(int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
        transposedMatrix[x][y] = matrix[y][x];
    }
}
return transposedMatrix;
}
}
```

Comment: `transposedMatrix` is name of method and also its local variable, try renaming the variable to something else

Comment: Your title has very little to do with the problem you have. Please change it to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: FYI there are a number of Matrix packages already out there; I used a NASA one years ago that was pretty good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your print statement to call the method you created. Make sure to also pass in the `originalMatrix`.

`printMatrix(transposedMatrix(originalMatrix));`

Also off topic but you have a memory leak in your code. You never close `Scanner` after using it. It is best practice to close your scanner after you are done using it.  Add this to the end of your `main` method to stop the memory leak.

`input.close()`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! 
I'm just a few weeks into java programming and haven't come across input.close() yet. I'll make sure to use that from now on, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("\nTransposed matrix:");
printMatrix(transposedMatrix);
```

this should be

```
System.out.println("\nTransposed matrix:");
printMatrix(transposedMatrix(originalMatrix));
```